# TypeError: in python in custom input function, exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, typeerror, valueerror

While creating a guess_the_number game in python, I wanted to catch the exception if user enters an invalid number, i.e. ValueError when typecasting the entered string to integer, I created a takeInput() function.
It works fine except for the part that when I raise an exception and enter a valid number after that, I get a TypeError.

```
import random
randInt = random.randint(1, 100)
count = 1
print("RandInt: " + str(randInt))


def takeInput(message):
    userInput = input(message)
    try:
        userInput = int(userInput)
        print("takeInput try " + str(userInput)) #This line is printing correct value every time
        return userInput
    except ValueError as e:
        takeInput("Not a valid number, try again: ")


userInput = takeInput("Please enter a number: ")

while(not(userInput == randInt)):
    print("while loop " + str(userInput)) #I am receiving a none value after I raise an exception and then enter a valid number
    if(userInput < randInt):
        userInput = takeInput("Too small, try again : ")
    else:
        userInput = takeInput("Too large, try again : ")
    count += 1

print("Congratulations, you guessed it right in " + str(count) + " tries.")
```

[image: This is output]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors and/or program output when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the terminal output, formatted like text. Also, make sure to **ask a question** when posting on Stack Overflow, as described in [ask]. "I got an error" is not sufficent. Please try to start with a question word like "why" or "how", and end with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: There are two possible questions here: one is about debugging the recursive code for `takeInput`, and the other is about how to *solve that problem* in the normal way. (It is not a good idea to use recursion for this problem.) Both questions are common duplicates, which I have now linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value of the function when an exception occurs. Since you're not returning anything, it returns `None` by default even when the function gets called.

```
def takeInput(message):
    userInput = input(message)
    try:
        userInput = int(userInput)
        print("takeInput try " + str(userInput)) #This line is printing correct value every time
        return userInput
    except ValueError as e:
        return takeInput("Not a valid number, try again: ")
```

---

A few things unrelated to the error,

- Try using snake_case and not camelCase in python.
- f strings are pretty nice, `print(f"takeInput try {userInput}")`
- Consider `while userInput != randInt:`

Comment: Yeah man, I figured this just after posting this question xD, Thanks btw!!